# Priority Queue contains method always returns false though elemenet exist in priority queue

Tags: java, collections, contains, priority-queue

Priority Queue contains method always returns false though element exist in priority queue. I am not getting to know how and where to override the compare method. This is the program for Dijkstra algorithm using adjacency List.
How to implement @Override compare method in this code.

```
 import java.util.*;
class dijkstra{
class AdjListNode{
    private int vertex,weight;
    AdjListNode(int v,int w){vertex=v;weight=w;}
    int getv(){return vertex;}
    int getw(){return weight;}        
@Override
    public boolean equals(AdjListNode obj){
        return (obj.getv() == this.vertex && obj.getw()==this.weight);
    }
}
class Graph{
    private int V;
    private LinkedList<AdjListNode> adj[];
    Graph(int v){
        V=v;
        adj=new LinkedList[v];
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
            adj[i]=new LinkedList<AdjListNode>();
        }
    }
    void addEdge(int u,int v,int w){
        //undirected graph so edges are added bothways
        AdjListNode node1=new AdjListNode(v,w);
        adj[u].add(node1);
    }
    void print(){
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
            Iterator<AdjListNode> itr=adj[i].listIterator();
            System.out.print(i+"==>");
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                AdjListNode node=itr.next();
                System.out.print("("+node.getv()+","+node.getw()+") ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    void sssp(int src){
        PriorityQueue<AdjListNode> q = new PriorityQueue<AdjListNode>(V, new Comparator<AdjListNode>() {
              @Override
              public int compare(AdjListNode node1, AdjListNode node2) {
                  return Integer.compare(node1.getw(), node2.getw());
              }
        });
        q.add(new AdjListNode(0,0));
        int dist[]=new int[V];
        Arrays.fill(dist,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        dist[src]=0;
        while(q.size()!=0){
            AdjListNode node=q.peek();
            Iterator<AdjListNode> itr=adj[node.getv()].listIterator();
            q.poll();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                AdjListNode temp=itr.next();
                if(dist[temp.getv()]>dist[node.getv()]+temp.getw()){
                    int oldweight=dist[temp.getv()];
                    dist[temp.getv()]=dist[node.getv()]+temp.getw();
                    //System.out.println(node.getv()+" "+temp.getv()+" "+oldweight+" "+q.contains(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),oldweight)));
                    if(q.contains(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),oldweight))){
                        System.out.println("yes");
                        q.remove(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),oldweight));
                        q.add(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),dist[temp.getv()]));
                    }                           
                    else{
                        q.add(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),dist[temp.getv()]));
                        //System.out.println(q.contains(new AdjListNode(temp.getv(),dist[temp.getv()])));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
            System.out.print(dist[i]+" ");
    }

}
Graph newGraph(int vertices){
    return new Graph(vertices);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    dijkstra d=new dijkstra();
    Graph g=d.newGraph(6);
    g.addEdge(0,1,2);
    g.addEdge(0,3,30);
    g.addEdge(0,5,40);
    g.addEdge(0,4,5);
    g.addEdge(0,2,60);
    g.addEdge(1,4,11);
    g.addEdge(1,3,5);
    g.addEdge(1,2,2);
    g.addEdge(1,5,4);
    g.addEdge(2,1,3);
    g.addEdge(2,3,1);
    g.addEdge(2,4,3);
    g.addEdge(3,4,3);
    g.addEdge(3,5,11);
    g.addEdge(4,3,2);
    g.addEdge(4,5,12);
    g.print();
    g.sssp(0);
}
```

}

The output is not showing any error and returning the correct result but there is some error going on and contains method is not working. Please suggest the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `equals` method in `AdjListNode` (and `hashCode` as well, in a way that is consistent with your `equals` implementation, though in this particular case I believe the method isn't called directly, but it's a good practice that will prevent lots of problems in the future).

The contains method requires this method to check if two objects in the queue are identical, and the default implementation in Object only checks if they are the exact same instance, which is not the case in your algorithm (at a quick glance)

Comment: i tried this but got an error...method doesnot implement or override a method from supertype

Comment: Can you show me your attempted `equals` implementation?

Comment: If you override `equals`, always override `hashCode` as well, in a way consistent with `equals`.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're absolutely right, and I've expanded the answer to include it. The reason I didn't cover it to begin with is because the implementation of `contains` in `PriorityQueue` does not call `hashCode`, so it is not necessary to solve the problem, but it is most definitely something that should be taught right alongside "override equals" so it merited an update

Comment: I have implemented this for equals()

@Override
 public boolean equals(AdjListNode obj){
         return (obj.getv() == this.vertex && obj.getw()==this.weight);
      }